# Referencing WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security in Windows Phone Store App via Nuget

Tags: .net, azure, windows-phone, nuget, azure-mobile-services

I try to reference WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security in a windows phone store app as shown in this tutorial.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users/

When I run nuget:

```
PM> install-package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security
```

I get the following error:

```
...
Adding 'Owin 1.0' to xxxx.WindowsPhone.
Uninstalling 'Owin 1.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Owin 1.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Could not install package 'Owin 1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content 
files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I tried all versions of the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security package without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Owin NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin/) only has assemblies for .NET 4.0 so you cannot install it into a Windows Phone Application.

Looking at the tutorial they add the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security NuGet package into the server side web application. On the Windows Phone App side they just call the web service exposed by the server side web application.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks!
How do I get the code (Visual Studio Project) of the server-side web application and how do I deploy them back on the service(azure server)? I can't find any hints in the tutorials.

Comment: The article links to another Mobile Services Quickstart tutorial where they create the server side app. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/